# Google Forms - Take (Long) Existing Form and Add Answer-Based Page Navigation Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I used scripting to create a Google Form with 200 + pages (generally only one question per page, though) and now need to add the branching logic to it. By the way, the new Forms gets really slow with this many pages.

Anyone know if I can use (Google) Sheets together with Forms and a script to create answer-based branching logic? I would envision Column A would be the question numbers and columns B-n would be used to point to question numbers based upon the answer. If needed, I could repeat the answer value in this exercise.

Assuming setChoices along with item.createChoice can do this.

Thanks

Comment: A Google Form can not be dynamically updated as the person filling out the Form has it open.  If that's what you are trying to do.  You can use an HTML form in an Apps Script Web App to do what you want.

Comment: Nope. I am not trying to dynamically update the form while it is being filled out - all of the potential questions and answers are in the form already. I have a spreadsheet that I created with Answer Mappings that I'd like to apply to my form via script rather than editing the form in Forms. Simple example: 1. Are you a cat or a dog person? (choice 1 goto page 2, choice 2 goto page 4) ...

Comment: There is no Apps Script method to set the "Go To" navigation based on the answer.  It can only be done manually.  You could add a feature request to the Issue Tracker [https://issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: There is an option for each form entry "Go to section based on answer".  In the lower right hand corner of the form editor there is a vertical ellipse (3 dots) if that is useful.